# Could not connect. server may not be running. MYSQL(Windows)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I just installed MYSQL on my PC. But whenever I try to use the workbench, it is saying

```
Could not connect. server may not be running.
```

I did a full install of mysql-installer-community-8.0.25.0
[image]

Comment: Look in services to see if the service _"MYSQL"_ is actually started. Just key _"services"_ in to the _"Search for anything"_ box on the left of the taskbar

Comment: That service seems to be missing from my computer
https://imgur.com/OuE3jYe

Comment: Did the install have any problems

Comment: Ok, I found the service but now it's showing this error https://imgur.com/TJUAjUw

Comment: Keyin "event viewer" in the same place as before, wait while it loads, click "windows logs" in the left hand menu, then "Applications" below the "Windows Logs" and look for error message from MYSQL

Comment: Tried but couldn't found any error message from MYSQL https://imgur.com/dOWE5LI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232287/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-tilak-bhattacharya).

Answer (score 3):

May be your mysql service has been stopped somehow. Go to task manager, open services, select mysql80 and start the service.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).